# Spotify web playback sdk define types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I try to use spotify's web playback sdk, I'm stuck with specifying the type.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { getAccessToken } from '../store/reducers/rootReducer';

function WebPlayBack() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
      const player = new window.Spotify.Player({
        name: 'Mucketlist',
        getOauthToken: (cb: any) => {
          cb(getAccessToken('')),
        },
        volume: 0.5,
      });
      player.addListener("ready", ({ device_id }) => {
        console.log("Ready with Device ID", device_id);
      });

      player.addListener("not_ready", ({ device_id }) => {
        console.log("Device ID has gone offline", device_id);
      });

      player.connect();
    }
  }, []);
  return <div></div>;
}

export default WebPlayBack;
```

The opaque type in the above function is onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady, Spotify, device_id.
I searched the reference in the Spotify official documentation, but there is no information about the type. How to solve it?